# Discriminated type unions

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

Is there a way to mimic TypeScript's discriminated type unions in Haskell? I want to do the following:

```hs
data A = B | C | D
data W = X | Y | Z

data FinalType = A | W
```

I know the last definition will create two value constructors `A` and `W` for `FinalType`. I can make the `FinalType` correctly in the following way right now:

```
data FinalType = B | C | D | X | Y | Z
```

But this isn't very neat and gets annoying after a lot of value constructors are added. Is there a way to mitigate this in Haskell?

Comment: `data FinalType = A A | W W`? Or you could just use the existing `Either` type constructor with a type synonym: `type FinalType = Either A W`.

Comment: Can you provide TS snippet? You may also explain why you use unions that way. Maybe there is idiomatic Haskell alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Robin Zigmond suggested,

```
data FinalType = A A | W W
```

will work. This takes on values like `A B`, `A C`, and `W Z`. Unless you need laziness here (relatively unlikely), you should probably make the constructors strict:

```
data FinalType = A !A | W !W
```

This way, calculating a value of type `FinalType` is guaranteed to calculate its actual contents.

Note that unlike Typescript's union types, Haskell's sum types are always discriminated. That's the role the `A` and `W` constructors play here, instead of having a common field to indicate which type is in use. A beginner may be confused by the overloading of the `A` and `W` names; you could be more explicit by instead defining

```
data FinalType = FinalA A | FinalW W
```

Comment: Thanks this does it for me I guess. Although is there a way to do a normal type union in haskell? Like I get direct access to value constructors of `A` and `W` in `FinalType`?

Comment: @HariomNarang, no, that's not really a thing in Haskell.